# WordPress save to database (ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

So I have this code (PHP and jQuery), it's supposed to save data into WordPress database and detect if the post already exists in the database. If the post exists, echo "Already saved".

Problem is, it saves some items and doesn't save others. I'm not sure what else to do to debug this issue.

```
public static function wpnp_save_news(){
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'wpnp';

        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
          if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $wpdb->delete( $table_name, array( 'id' => $id ) );
            echo "Article deleted";
          }elseif (isset($_POST['savefav'])) {
            $user = $_POST['user_id'];
            $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
            $sql = "SELECT count(*)  FROM $table_name  WHERE user=$user and title='".$title."'";
            $count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);


          if($count <= 0 ){
              $wpdb->insert(
                $table_name,
                array(
                  'user' => $_POST['user_id'],
                  'title' => $_POST['title'],
                  'summary' => $_POST['summary'],
                  'url' => $_POST['post_url'],
                  'img' => $_POST['img_url'],
                  'author' => $_POST['author'],
                  'source' => $_POST[ 'source']
                )
                );
                echo "Article saved";
            }else{
                echo "Article already saved";
            }
          }else{
            echo "Please login to save articles";
          }
        }
      wp_die();
      } 
-----------------------------------------
$('.wpnp-delete').on('click',(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const url = wpnpObj.au;
        const delete_data = {
          action: wpnpObj.ff,
          'delete': true,
          'id': e.currentTarget.dataset.id
        };
        const success = data =>{
          alert(data)
          window.location.reload()
        };
        const err = data =>{
          console.log(data);
        }
      $.post(url,delete_data,success).fail(err);
})
```

Comment: One thing you need to change in your sql query. Concat $user variable as well. like you have done for $title variable.

Comment: `user_id` is primary key in table `$wpdb->prefix.'wpnp';`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. The SQL query was properly formed but it's always a good practice to be consistent hence, I re-concatenated the query string as @rana had suggested but that wasn't the problem.

The problem was, in the database, the column `summary` had a `max-length` of 200 so `wpdb` ignored saving those items who's length exceeded 200 characters. I reduced the string length and now everything works fine.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Read about how to properly use `$wpdb` instead.